# Placing a block on an entity

Tags: 8, entities, blocks

I am aiming to **place a block on an entity**.

It seems like this should be simple as entity integration in D8 is well-developed and (in parts) user-friendly.

I can get the view block working fine and can 'Place Block' on different content types successfully.

However when it comes to entities there are no options in the 'Configure Block: Visibility' tabs.

Perhaps there is some standard documentation on customising the appearance of entities in this way that I just cant seem to find?

D8 seems to have integrated entities quite well with Views etc. But somehow simply placing a block on an entity remains a challenge.

I expect other relatively less experienced users would be experiencing the same challenges.

Perhaps I am missing something very obvious. If so perhaps someone could let me know! :-)

Thoughts and guidance welcome.

Comment: What have you tried so far? There are sooo many modules that can do this... the very obvious are Core's Layout Builder, Block field module, EVA module, Views reference field module. Have not used those modules personally, but should work too: Page Manager, Display Suite, Panels

Comment: Thanks - yes it seems Core is still oriented around node content (which makes sense I guess) and it sounds like we need to invoke another layer to customise the appearance of entities. I have used Page Manager, Display Suite and Panels before and found them quite heavy-handed for what I wanted to do. Will have a look at the others - thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: As I understand you only want a visibility condition for entities other than nodes. There is an open issue https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/1932810 and ctools also provides such a plugin. If it is about a custom entity then at the moment it is probably expected that the module which provides the entity also provides the condition plugin.

Comment: Thank you - yes that is correct. The entities I am aiming to modify the appearance of are provided by the bibcite module (Reference and Contributor). Ideally these would somehow appear in the visibility tabs for determining where blocks appear.
I have ctools installed. Is there somewhere I should be looking to activate a plugin that might make these entities amenable to customisation in the same manner as nodes in this respect?